# About Centralizers of two elements of a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group, and suppose $b$ belongs to $G$ with $|b|=7$. Prove that $C(b)=C(b^4)$.

I'm not entirely familiar with centralizers, if someone could give me a push in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

edit: edited title

Answer (score 3):

For a general  element $g\in G$ to commute with a given element $b$ is equivalent to requiring that $g$ commute with all the elements of the cyclic subgroup generated by $b$. (You can easily verify this).

Now for your problem $b$ is of order $7$ means $b^4$ is also of order $7$ and hence it  generates the same cyclic subgroup as $b$. This settles your question.

(Your title should be descriptive. The way you have given title makes the body of your post incomplete).

Comment: I'm still new to writing these questions, what should I add to the title that would make it more appealing?

Comment: Make the existing title the first sentence of your post. Give a new title something like "About Centralizers of two elements of a group"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: But I suggested old title should be moved to the body of the post as first line.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $C(b)=C(H)$, where $H$ is the group generated by $b$.  What do you know about the group generated by $b^4$?